# (NestJS) How to change name of uploaded file?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I'm using nestjs libraries to uploads files, but this files are stored without a file extension

```js
@Post('upload')
@UseInterceptors(
  FilesInterceptor('files', 6, {
    dest: 'images',
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
      file.filename = Date.now() + '-' +file.originalname ;
      cb(null, true);
    },
  })

)
uploadFile(
  @UploadedFiles() files
){
  console.log(files);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@robinson-ortiz, you can check what does mutter takes a options, from docs: [multer:diskstorage](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#diskstorage) it says:

`filename` callback that can be used to setup file name on disk, try:

```
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    console.log(file);
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
  }
```

you will see what fields are usable for you to determine how to store file on disk.

But from my experience, best way is to store this as metadata in DB, and store files on disk as "some file", without any extension, or even name that will suggest what it can be. Fe: use `node-uuid` with `v4` function.

Why? Because it doesn't generate any storage hell, like how about different users might upload the same file name but with totally different content. But it still depends on what you are trying to achieve, when you split their storage by subfolders this might never happen, but when you store everything in the same spot  (fe you're storing everything in one bucket on S3) it might happen.

Now, the limitation of files in one folder is so big, that you don't even need to think about.

Regards.